# Problems with my batch code. Not detecting nor changing the desired characters

Tags: batch-file

This part of my code is supposed to run by all the lines of a file, detecting the **percent signs** and changing to **double percent signs**. And then, echo the result.

Heres my code:

```
@echo off

REM | Using this line to test the code: % %% %%% %test%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ( %~0 ) do set %a=!%a:%%=%%%%! & echo %%a
pause
```

And this is the output it is generating:

```
@echo off 
REM | Using this line to test the code: % %% %%% %test% 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ( %~0 ) do set %a=%%=%%%% & echo %%a 
pause
```

What is wrong with it? I can't seem to find any problems with the line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find/replace does not work with FOR variables. It only works with environment variables. So you must transfer the `%%a` value to an environment variable, and then use the environment variable to do the find/replace.

The expansion is within a parenthesized block (part of the FOR loop) so you must use delayed expansion. FOR loops will corrupt values containing `!` if delayed expansion is enabled when the FOR variable is expanded. So delayed expansion must be toggled on and off within the loop.

There is no need to change the variable and then echo the new value. Simply echo the changed value directly, without storing the new value in the variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
REM | Using this line to test the code: % %% %%% %test%
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~f0") do (
  set "str=%%a"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo !str:%%=%%%%!
  endlocal
)
pause
```

Comment: Not only worked perfectly but also taught me something new. Thank you, sir! ^-^